# sending post request in angular not working

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying top send a post request on angular and im pretty sure that the problem is not in the backend side since i used postman and it worked on postman.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class ConHttpService {
  private headers: HttpHeaders;
  private accessPointUrl: string = 'https://localhost:44340/api/contact';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.headers = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'});
  }


  public addcon(payload) {
    console.log("hi") //prints hi
   console.log(this.accessPointUrl, payload, {headers: this.headers}) //gives a link that take me to a url full of json of targeted database but without my added object
    return this.http.post(this.accessPointUrl, payload, {headers: this.headers});
  }
}
```

in the sending component:

```
  onSubmit(){
    console.log(this.contactForm.value)
    this.conhttp.addcon(this.contactForm.value)
  }
```

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: its not giving an error , it just dont make any action (not adding it to database)

Comment: Can you check the Network tab of your debugger to see if there's a network error? What's the request look like? What's the response look like? If nothing is out of the ordinary, I'm pretty sure it's your backend.

Comment: @Joseph i tested the api via postman and it's working 100%. but as u said nothing is out of ordinary and my request is not showing in my network tab.

Comment: To initiate the XHR, the code needs to execute the observable's `.subscribe` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HttpClient.post()` returns an observable. In order to invoke the operation, you need to call `subscribe()` on that observable.

```
this.conhttp
  .addcon(this.contactForm.value)
  .subscribe()
```